# How do I apply layout changes to only certain Next.js App Router pages (without using Route Groups)?

Tags: next.js, app-router

I'm building a website with Next.js and App Router and need to have three types of navigation Headers. (background=white, background=black, and one version where all nav items are hidden except for "Free Trial" and "Request Demo").

This is my current LocaleLayout

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { getTranslations, unstable_setRequestLocale } from "next-intl/server";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import Header from "@/src/components/header/Header";
import Footer from "@/src/components/footer/Footer";
import { locales } from "@/src/config";
import "../styles.css";

// ... other code

export default async function LocaleLayout({
  children,
  params: { locale },
  headerBackground = true,
  simpleHeader = false,
}: Props) {
  // Validate that the incoming `locale` parameter is valid
  if (!locales.includes(locale as any)) notFound();

  // Enable static rendering
  unstable_setRequestLocale(locale);

  return (
    <html lang={locale} className={`${inter.className} scroll-smooth`}>
      <head>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1"
        />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Header /> // this Header I want to split into variants
        <main className="pt-navigation-height mx-auto w-full max-w-[1274px] px-8 sm:px-[66px] lg:px-[125px]">
          {children}
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

The only solution I found is using "Route Groups", i.e. I have to create a group for each Header type (header with black background, header with white background, header with just two CTA buttons). This gets messy pretty quickly and if I want to combine Header variants with Footer Variants, my folder and routes structure becomes pure chaos.

```
- (header variant 1)
-- (footer variant 1)
--- layout.tsx
-- (footer variant 2)
--- layout.tsx
- (header variant 2)
-- (footer variant 1)
--- layout.tsx
-- (footer variant 2)
--- layout.tsx
```

... and so on

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this or are Route Groups really the only way?

Thanks for your help.

PS: I wish there was something like this from the static site generator Hugo that simply let's me set a frontmatter parameter that targets a certain layout on a "per Page" level without having to nest everything in folders and subfolders
https://gohugo.io/content-management/front-matter/#layout